# Insert Overwrite in Hive is not loading the data although it runs ok.

Tags: insert, hive, overwrite

I created the table and and ran Insert Overwrite to load selected data from tables but it not loading the data although it runs ok. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the code you tried to run?

Comment: post your error logs so we can help..

Answer (score 0):

Check if your select query returns 0 records. If so, old data doesn't get overwritten.

Comment: even select returns no resuluts

Answer (score 0):

As of Hive 0.14, if a table has an OutputFormat that implements AcidOutputFormat and the system is configured to use a transaction manager that implements ACID, then INSERT OVERWRITE will be disabled for that table.  This is to avoid users unintentionally overwriting transaction history.  The same functionality can be achieved by using TRUNCATE TABLE (for non-partitioned tables) or DROP PARTITION followed by INSERT INTO.

This might be your case

Comment: I have like syntax which works for simple select statement but when I do run this with insert into (insert into along with select query which has 5 jobs), it doesn't feed the output.